# How's Jasmine's `done()` implemented?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I've used Jasmine for years and I'm now writing some code that could be implemented using a similar `done()` concept for handling *optional* async params. I tried digging around their source but I'm not sure how `done()` works. Say I have this code:

```
new Validator({
    element: someElement,
    validator: function (value, done) {
        doSomeStuffAsyncThenCall(done)
    }
});
```

How does that work? The part that I'm hitting a wall on is getting the arguments of that function. I can get validator with, say, `this.options.validator` but how do I get if `done` is defined *and* how do I call it?

Comment: @zerkms could you elaborate?

Comment: "The part that I'm hitting a wall on is getting the arguments of that function". What do you actually want to get? You could get the arity of the function via `length` and use that, assuming the presence of a 2nd argument always indicates async behaviour. You could also use `toString` and parse the values you need out of the stringified function.

Comment: @zerkms i stated in my question: "I tried digging around their source...". For example, this is how they catch async calls that last too long `Function.prototype.apply.apply`. It's a lot of pseudo code and I'm not sure how it works. This is the file that has tests attached to it for `done()` https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/master/src/core/QueueRunner.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your question as follows. You want to detect if a function has a second argument and if so, do something else. So, you have a function X that can be passed a function Y. If Y has two arguments, then you would like to asynchronously call Y with a function Z as second parameter and wait for Z to be called, otherwise you just wait until Y returns and then continue.

Given a function Y, you can determine how many arguments it has using [`Function.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length). This can be used to have different code paths as follows.

```js
function X(Y) {
  if (typeof(Y) !== 'function') {
    throw new Error('argument should be a function');
  }
  if (Y.length === 2) {
    // asynchronously call Y
    setTimeout(function() {
      Y('foo', function() {
        console.log('Y is done now (1)!');
      });
    }, 10);
  } else {
    Y('bar');
    console.log('Y is done now (2)!');
  }
}

X(function(arg, done) { console.log('Y(' + arg + ')'); done(); });
X(function(arg) { console.log('Y(' + arg + ')'); });
```

<sub>Thanks to [James Allardice](//stackoverflow.com/users/790695/james-allardice) for [helping me](//stackoverflow.com/q/43930746#comment74894747_43930890) improve this answer and understanding OP's question.</sub>

Comment: I think the issue is that the OP does not have control over the function itself so they can't check the type of the params. A consumer of their code will write the function and the OP needs to know if the consumer has provided a function with 2 arguments.

Comment: @JamesAllardice Ah, I see now that the question can also be read like that. So OP would like to know if a `Function` will do anything with its second parameter, ever? That sounds impossible... I'll keep my answer up, see if OP has comments on this.

Comment: No, I think they just need to know whether or not it has a 2nd param, not whether it does anything with it. This is what tools like Jasmine do - you write a test as a function, if you add a 2nd param to that function Jasmine will treat the test asynchronously and wait until you call the 2nd param (which will be a callback function) before moving onto your next test.

Comment: Yea what @JamesAllardice said. I want to allow people to add additional validations. My code needs to consume their `validator` function. If the 2nd param exists I want to make the validator async and not "complete" until `done` is called. This blog explains how Jasmine works a bit https://volaresystems.com/blog/post/2014/12/09/Testing-async-calls-with-Jasmine

Comment: Also worth mentioning, this is the file Jasmine has their own internal unit tests for `done` associated with but I'm not finding how done works here https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/master/src/core/QueueRunner.js

Comment: @OscarGodson I updated my answer, does this help you?

Comment: @OscarGodson You can see the part I put in my answer now [here](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/master/src/core/QueueRunner.js#L43). The async code in Jasmine is more complex, because it caters for timeouts and has error handling and such. That's the [`attemptAsync`](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/master/src/core/QueueRunner.js#L64) function. I can also explain that, if you want.

Comment: The key piece for me was that `this.options.validator.length`. I never knew that length was the length of the arguments! Thank you!